# How to generate 1000 prime number of 1024-bit with much less time?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, prime-numbers

I am generating  thousand prime number of 1024 bit each. But it takes lots of time. My procedure is as follows.  Generate prime number using

```
SecureRandom rnd=new SecureRandom();  
BigInteger num=num.probablePrime(No_of_bits,rnd);//here no_of_bits=1000
```

How to reduce the time so that 1000 or 2000 or 3000 prime numbers of 1000-bit are generated quickly. In [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/441.pdf), this process of generating prime number is done in very quickly. I want to match keygen timing of this paper. More as you will see remark 3.1 on page 492, the author generate rough $q_0$ using different technique in which large prime number  of $\lambda^2$ bits  (nearly 1000-bit) are multiplied to generate $q_0$. The author choose 4 schemes

toy $\longrightarrow$ keygen time 4.38 seconds-->As in remark 3.1 $q_0$ product of 90 prime number of nearly 1000-bit.

small $\longrightarrow$ keygen time 36 seconds $\longrightarrow$ As in remark 3.1 $q_0$ product of 317 prime number of $52^2$ bits

Medium $\longrightarrow$keygen time 5min 9 sec $\longrightarrow$ prdouct of 1092 prime number of $62^2$ bits

Large $\longrightarrow$ keygen time of 43 min $\longrightarrow$ product of 3665 prime number of $72^2$ bits.

How such large prime numbers are generated in such sort time. They have written that they use sage 4.5.3 and GMP4.3.2 for on single core2 DUO. As a note in result, they have also written that whole time of keygen is spent in primality testing.

Comment: Reusing the `rnd` would be a good idea to start with. Taxing the system RNG to seed `rng` may result in low performance.

Comment: Maarten Thanks for replying. But In this paper, toy scheme generates the public key of (8*10^6) bits in 4.38 seconds.  So this is product of 90 prime numbers of 1000 bits How that is possible?

Comment: what exactly is this: probablePrime(No_of_bits,rnd)?   Is this your own implementation or is it part of some library/package that you are using?  The speed obviously depends on the efficiency of the software implementation and the raw computational power of the hardware (CPU).

Comment: @A.Toumantsev It's from the [BigInteger API of Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#probablePrime-int-java.util.Random-). Java 9 will feature many performance benefits, [including RSA operations](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/246). And yes, this will also benefit key pair generation. So using the RNG better and upgrading to Java 9 pre-release will already have a huge impact. It won't match fully CPU optimized C/C++ implementations though.

Comment: @vivek: Why don't you ask the authors directly? Their mail addresses are given.

Comment: Robert Thanks for suggestion. I mailed to author, if I get anything I will share with you all guys.

Comment: See Fouque and Tibouchi 2011:  http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/481.  Tibouchi is an author on your paper as well, so it wouldn't surprise me if they used a method from this earlier paper.  I've found A1, modified to keep the top bit set, combined with a simple optimization that removes all multiples of 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19 with one mod, to be quite fast.  The TRIVIAL method is even faster, albeit with very non-uniform distribution.  Java's probable prime method will differ in speed and function from what others use, to some unknown degree.

Comment: @DanaJ Thanks for your comment. I do not understant what you want to say " I've found A1, modified to keep the top bit set, combined with a simple optimization that removes all multiples of 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19 with one mod, to be quite fast. The TRIVIAL method is even faster, albeit with very non-uniform distribution"

Comment: @DanaJ Can you tell me which algorithm Biginteger.probablePrime() use to generate prime numbers?

Comment: Correction for my comment: TRIVIAL should read PRIMEINC.  Trivial method is repeatedly picking a random integer and doing a primality test.  This gives good uniformity but can be slower than the other methods.  PRIMEINC picks a single random number then finds the next prime.  Minimum randomness used, fewest tests, but picks primes after large gaps far more often than ones after small gaps.

Comment: @vivek, v7 for < 95 bits uses a loop selecting random integers, doing a efficient pretest, then does a probable prime test.  For 95+ bits it seems to use a sieve to find the next probable prime after its random integer.  The probable prime test is 50 random-base M-R tests if under 100 bits, otherwise 2-27 random-base M-R tests followed by a non-strong Lucas test (which it mis-names Lucas-Lehmer).  I don't know if later Java versions have changed the code.

Comment: @DanaJ picking after large gaps. So. uniformity must be there also.

Comment: BigInteger's probable prime methods use both the Miller-Rabin and Lucas-Lehmer algorithms to test primality.
See the internal method BigInteger.primeToCertainty. at http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/math/BigInteger.java.html and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744085/difference-between-biginteger-probableprime-and-other-primality-algorithms